# Getting connection string from App.config and using it in a Linq dataContext

Tags: .net, data-binding, configuration, connection-string, system.configuration

How should I extract the following connection string and apply it to my Linq context?  I know the Linq portion, but am weak with the System.Configuration section.

```
  <connectionStrings>
        <!-- Production

        <add name="Management_Report_Emailer.Properties.Settings.DWConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=prodSQL01;Initial Catalog=DW;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->


      <!-- QA-->

      <add name="Management_Report_Emailer.Properties.Settings.DWConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=qaSQL01;Initial Catalog=DW;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Management_Report_Emailer.Properties.Settings.DWConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

Comment: Works for me, just had to replace parens, with brackets.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see anything talking about VB/C# so I just put it in the VB way.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Management_Report_Emailer.Properties.Settings.DWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```